# Variance of sum of datasets with different sampling intervals

Tags: variance, covariance, missing-data

I have two randomly distributed datasets which are to be added together element-wise, and I am looking to calculate the uncertainty of the mean of the result. One dataset had a sampling rate of 1 sample per 12 minutes (call it set A), the other sampled every minute (call it set B). The two are correlated.

I originally interpolated between the data points in set A to sum with set B. But I can't just take the variance of the resulting set and divide by $ \sqrt{N} $, since that will give an incorrect value (I believe). Originally I tried to just add the variances on A and B, but that's not right either because they're correlated. Finally, I don't think I can do a variance-covariance matrix because the different sampling rates mean that the sets are of different sizes.

How can I estimate the uncertainty on the mean of A+B?